# Spring Integration 4.1-4.2 migration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xmlns:int-event="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/event"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/event http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/event/spring-integration-event.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">
```

because of this file, I get following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use prior versions of Spring Integration schemas with Spring Integration 4.2. Please upgrade your schema declarations or use versionless aliases (e.g. spring-integration.xsd).
Offending resource: class path resource [com/improvedigital/yield360/services/status/ctx/application-config.xml]
```

I'm trying really hard to make this work, but I'm out of ideas...help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a mix of versions in your classpath.

I guess the picture is like:

1. You have `spring-integration-core-4.2.x`
2. one of your `spring-integration-http`, ``spring-integration-xml`,`spring-integration-amqp`or`spring-integration-core-event`is of version`4.1.x`.

When you upgrade to a new version you should do that for all Spring Integration modules at the same time.

The best way to achieve that is to use some Dependency Management tool like Maven or Gradle, when you can specify the version for bounded artifacts as a one variable in one place. During upgrade you'll just change that variable and that's all.

Comment: thank you for quick answer. I use Maven and I have one version variable for all of these. I checked once again Maven Dependencies in project, and all jars are latest version (4.2.4), except spring rabbit which is 1.5 latest (I tried to remove this one, but problem persist..and shouldn't be making problem anyway)

Comment: Well, or you have something else as your dependency (e.g. spring-boot-starter), or there is some `<import>` in your config which provides the config with XSD pointed to the `4.1` version.